# What was the mark on Lord Beckett left by Jack Sparrow?

Tags: pirates-of-the-caribbean, dead-mans-chest

What was the mark on Lord Beckett left by Jack Sparrow?

[image: Beckett: "And we've each left our mark on the other."]

We know the one on Jack is the P symbol on his arm, but what is the mark on Lord Beckett?

Comment: I think he means metaphorically.

Comment: could be but in order to be sure , ı had to ask.

Comment: When I saw that part of the movie, the back of my head was waiting the whole movie for his mark to be revealed (on his arm, or whatever). I always thought it was phisical.

Comment: Per the wiki "*Since Sparrow's act **ruined his chance to join the British nobility**, Beckett ordered his men to burn the Wench and personally branded Sparrow as a pirate.*"

Comment: @Richard Which act ?

Comment: "*Not only Sparrow didn't bring him the bearings of Kerma, but he also liberated a cargo of slaves which Beckett's patron Lord Penwallow needed for his plantation in the Bahamas*"; http://pirates.wikia.com/wiki/Cutler_Beckett